# Add template popup to GeoJSON component with Python Dash-Leaflet

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am a very beginner in programmation and Python. I have a map application built with dash-leaflet with several (~10) GeoJSON files included by **dl.GeoJSON** component. I would like to show a popup with all the properties of each file. Before dl.GeoJSON was implemented, i used to create my layers by reading my geojson and defining popup like this :

```
def compute_geojson(gjson):

    geojson = json.load(open(gjson["path"],encoding='utf8'))
    if 'Polygon' in geojson["features"][0]["geometry"]["type"]:
        data = [
            dl.Polygon(
                positions=get_geom(feat),
                children=[
                    dl.Popup([html.P(k + " : " + str(v)) for k,v in feat["properties"].items()],maxHeight=300),
                ],
                color=get_color(gjson,feat), weight=0.2, fillOpacity=gjson["opacity"], stroke=True
            ) for feat in geojson['features']
        ]
...
```

I would like to do this for all my geojson (which have different structures) with the component dl.GeoJSON because it should render faster than my method. Is it possible ? I tried some javascript with *onEachFeature* but didn't succeed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a feature named `popup` with the desired popup content, as the `GeoJSON` component will render it as a popup automatically,

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_leaflet.express as dlx

data = dlx.dicts_to_geojson([dict(lat=-37.8, lon=175.6, popup="I am a popup")])
geojson = dl.GeoJSON(data=data)
```

If you need more customization options and/or prefer not to add properties (e.g. for performance reasons), you would need to implement a custom `onEachFeature` function. If you create a .js file in your assets folder with content like,

```
window.someNamespace = Object.assign({}, window.someNamespace, {
    someSubNamespace: {
        bindPopup: function(feature, layer) {
            const props = feature.properties;
            delete props.cluster;
            layer.bindPopup(JSON.stringify(props))
        }
    }
});
```

you can bind the function like this,

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash_extensions.javascript import Namespace

ns = Namespace("someNamespace", "someSubNamespace")
geojson = dl.GeoJSON(data=data, options=dict(onEachFeature=ns("bindPopup")))
```

In the above code examples i am using `dash-leaflet==0.1.10` and `dash-extensions==0.0.33`.

Comment: The first option needs to read my files that i would like to avoid.
The second solution with javascript do the job, great ! Thanks for the quick reply !

Comment: Great! If you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as the solution. Otherwise, please let me know how I can improve :)